# Where is blitz/tinyvec.h in blitz 0.10?

Tags: c++, blitz++

I had used blitz 0.09 for a long time. Currently I updated it to blitz 0.10. And the blitz/tinyvec.h is gone. There is a similar one blitz/tinyvec2.h. I change to it, but compilation doesn't pass. I have to include blitz/array.h to pass the compilation. How can I just include a short tinyvec header file in blitz 0.10 since I only use tiny vectors? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `tinyvec.h` was removed about a year an half ago: http://blitz.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/blitz/blitz/rev/49f4a83346b6?revcount=240  It seems that `tinyvec2.h` is what you're expected to use now; is there a problem with having to include `array.h` to be able to use `tinyvec2.h`?

Comment: @Michael Burr No problem to include array.h. But I think compilation time may be longer if I only use tiny vectors. When using tinyvec2.h, link error, cannot find it. One more question: is blitz++ 0.10 better than 0.09? And if so, in what ways? Thanks.

Comment: I can't comment on the difference between blitz versions - I just don't know.  I wouldn't worry about any increased compilation time from including `array.h` unless compilation time becomes a problem after adding `array.h`.

Comment: Unfortunately, tinyvec2.h is rather incompatible to tinyvec.h (e.g. numElements is a function and no longer a compile time constant expression etc.), so a proper answre would probably be: "It is gone without replacement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that `blitz/tinyvec2.h` will compile if you also include `blitz/tinyvec2.cc`.

I hope that helps.